# How does an instance contain multiple instances of other classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I'm creating a basic game to help understand classes, where by the `Player()` instance (Ben), owns a number of buildings and units. Each player, such as ben will have various buildings such as a Plane factory or Bot Factory.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 200
        self.score = 0
        print('Created ')

    def increase_money(self, amount):
        self.money += amount

    def decrease_money(self, amount):
        self.money -= amount

    def check_money(self):
        print(self.money)


class Building(Player):

    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        self.upgrade_cost = 100
        print('created building')

    def upgrade_building(self):
        self.level += 1

    def check_building_level(self):
        print(self.level)

ben = Player()
```

I have realised that if I call the `Building()` class to create an instance, it actually creates an building instance that inherit the properties of player (i.e. each building would have its own money).

How would I have each player contain various buildings and units with different properties? For example, Ben and Bill have different buildings. In this case, would I use a single `Player()` class and then use functions inside of `Player()`?

Comment: You are not looking for inheritance but composition. You will need to a class variable in `Player` that manages the list of `Building`s the player contains. (And not inherit from Player).

Comment: Despite your confusion about the topic, you managed to write a clear question. I wish this was true for all new users asking questions. +1

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `Building` inheriting from `Player` does not make much sense, a *is-a* relationship between `Building` and `Player` seems weird and like a semantic error.

Just don't inherit from `Player`, i.e.:

```
class Building(object):
     # code for the class
```

Now for your other question, if you want each `Player` to be able to aggregate multiple instances of `Building` objects, you could make each instance of `Player` have a collection attribute (a list or a set) to store the `Building` instances.

To achieve this, you can add the line

```
self.buildings = []
```

to the `__init__` method of `Player`. Initially, this list will be empty. To add a building for a specific player, append to its `buildings` attribute, for example:

```
p = Player()
p.buildings.append(Building())
p.buildings.append(Building())
p.buildings[1].upgrade_building()
```

The player `p` now has two buildings, and the second one is upgraded once. This is just a general demo of how you can do it. I can't say much more without more information about the direction you want your program to take.

Answer (score 2):

Your player constructions don't have an attribute to track buildings owned. Your buildings don't have an owner, either. So you need:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 200
        self.score = 0
        self.buildings = []
        print('Created ')

    def increase_money(self, amount):
        self.money += amount

    def add_building(self, Building):
    #Here's what to call when we construct a new building with the owner
        self.buildings.append(Building):

    def decrease_money(self, amount):
        self.money -= amount

    def check_money(self):
        print(self.money)


class Building:
    def __init__(self, Owner, Type)
#Constructor now requires an Owner and Type:
        self.level = 0
        self.owner = Owner
        self.Type = Type
        self.upgrade_cost = 100
        print('created building')
        Owner.add_building(self) #And now we will add this to the owner's buildings set

    def upgrade_building(self):
        self.level += 1

    def check_building_level(self):
        print(self.level)
```

To create a building, you'll call it like so:

```
P = player()
B1 = Building(P, "Building type")
```

and this will add to the player's list of owned buildings. In addition, you can look at each building for an owner ("How many Bot Factories are built?"). You can also look at the player for their buildings.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you instantiate several instances of the same class, player, and add them different buildings:

    Ben = Player()
    Bill = Player()
    B1 = Building(Ben, "type1")
    B2 = Building(Bill, "type2")

Answer (score 0):

So this is answer is more for reference purposes - someone who may be trying to do the same sort of thing.

I actually found the best way to do it, and cleanest was to call the Building class from the Player class:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 200
        self.score = 0
        print('Created ')
        self.bot_factory = Building('Bot Factory') # [1]
        self.vehicle_factory = Building('Vehicle Factory')

    def increase_money(self, amount):
        self.money += amount

    def decrease_money(self, amount):
        self.money -= amount

    def check_money(self):
        print(self.money)


class Building(Player):

    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        self.upgrade_cost = 100
        print('created building')

    def upgrade_building(self):
        self.level += 1

    def check_building_level(self):
        print(self.level)

ben = Player()
```

This way, each player, such as Ben has their own versions of the bot_factory and vehicle_factory. I then intend to upgrade the buildings by a call such as `ben.building_upgrade('bot','upgrade')`, which calls the Building functions from the Player class.